# Using mathabx and MnSymbol in the same document

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I'm not a computer expert, so when I simply include the lines

```
\include{mathabx, MnSymbol}
```

in a `.tex` file, compile it, and it gives me a bunch of errors, I don't know what to do... I'm running MikTeX in Windows.

Comment: please be more specific about what errors you see.  it *might* have something to do with fonts not being installed, but it might also indicate conflicts between those two packages.  more information is needed.

Comment: The error says, Command `\ulcorner' already defined. ......lcorner}{\mathopen} {AMSa}{"70}{AMSa}{"70}." I was trying to use the command \lefttorightarrow.

Comment: the "already defined" error indicates a conflict between packages.  perhaps you don't need all the symbols defined in these two packages.  to access symbols selectively, see the question [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the correct way to load these two packages would be to write these lines in the preamble

```
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

and not

```
\include{mathabx, MnSymbol}
```

With the latter, LaTeX will try to include the file `mathabx,.tex` in your main file...

---

Anyway, these two packages are not compatible because `MnSymbol` automatically loads the `amsmath` package which isn't compatible with `mathabx`.

`MnSymbol` can be loaded with the option `abx` if you just need to use the calligraphic font from the `mathabx` fonts.

Instead, follow the link suggested by Barbara Beeton in her comment if you need to "access symbols selectively", using her words.

Comment: Thanks! I mostly learn by examples, and I thought one could use multiple packages simply by separating them by commas. Why would LaTeX do such a stupid thing as trying to include mathabx,.tex?

Comment: Are you sure you did intend to write `\include{mathabx, MnSymbol}` and not `\usepackage{mathabx, MnSymbol}` in your question?