# "Too many math alphabets" with Beamer and DeclareSymbolFont

Tags: beamer, fonts, amsmath

The following is a near-minimal example of my problem:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\DeclareSymbolFont{bbsymbol}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbsemi}{\mathbin}{bbsymbol}{"3B}

% Import some stuff from mathabx.sty -- because mathabx.sty incompatible with
% amsmath package.
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    $\mathbf{0} \mathsf{hello}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to use stmaryrd and MnSymbol in the same doc. I would also like some stuff from mathabx, but because of incompatibility with amsmath (which is imported automatically by MnSymbol), I use DeclareSymbolFont to import it, as described in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117971/using-mathabx-and-mnsymbol-in-the-same-document). Moreover I would also like to define a blackboard semicolon operator, and so I also use DeclareSymbolFont to introduce bbsymbol. Finally I want mathbf and mathsf.

Unfortunately this seems to run out of space for math alphabets in Beamer, but not (for example) if I build a regular article.

Is there a solution that meets all my requirements, for Beamer? (It seems that deleting any one of the imported or defined fonts fixes the problem, but then I don't have all my requirements satisfied.)

Comment: You can look here for a diagnosis: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/diagnosing-the-too-many-math-alphabets-error; there are methods for loading only the needed symbols, if they are few, without wasting a math alphabet. Note that `MnSymbol` is rather hungry in this respect.

Comment: Yes, I saw this, thanks. I managed to work around it in the end by loading what I need from stmaryrd. I wasted some time trying to do the same with MnSymbol, but as the symbol codes don't appear in the .sty file this wasn't so easy.

(As an aside, I guess this is a case where a "minimal example" may not be that useful, since the best solution to this problem seems to depend on exactly how you are using the packages in question.)

Comment: Can you add a self-answer describing what you did?

Comment: Re the problem of looking up the symbol codes in MnSymbol, I found this helpful: `texdef -tlatex -pMnSymbol lhookswarrow`. The output contains `\lhookswarrow: \mathchar"3436` and that tells me that the symbol is at position "36 in math alphabet "34, but you can look at the `MnSymbol.sty` file to see that the alphabet is `MnSyA`.

Comment: @dubiousjim Oh, that's pretty awesome to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I added the following after the `\DeclareFontFamily` business above:

```
% Use these in preference to stmaryrd (to avoid math alphabet limits).
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ldbrack}{3}{matha}{"76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rdbrack}{3}{matha}{"77}
```

So it looks like I pulled in the characters I needed from `mathabx` rather than `stmaryrd` in the end.

I'm not sure if this counts as an answer to my original question, but I've posted it here in case it's useful anyway.

Comment: This does not help in my case: when I just load `MnSymbol` only in `beamer`, regardless whether I add your stuff or not, `xelatex` gets stuck on `Latex Error: Command \mathdollar already defined.`