# “Too many math alphabets” error on one machine but not another

Tags: math-mode, fonts

It sometimes happens to me that I take a document from one machine, where it compiled without error, to another, where it produces a `Too many math alphabets in version normal` error.  (Related: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125769/too-many-math-alphabets-with-beamer-and-declaresymbolfont), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/diagnosing-the-too-many-math-alphabets-error), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error).)  How can that be?

The two systems are quite similar (Ubuntu with TeX Live / Debian with TeX Live).  There are no other errors, and the document seems to render correctly.

I have no MWE, but the document that prompted this question is a presentation made with `beamer` in [`arev`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/).  It includes the lines

```
\makeatletter
% get sans-serif \sum from Euler
\DeclareSymbolFont{EulerExtension}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\sum@\mathop{EulerExtension}{"50}
\makeatother
```

If I remove these lines, the error disappears.  However, even with them I see no errors in the compiled PDF (I use pdflatex).  Even the Euler sum sign is displayed as requested.

Comment: 'Quite similar' is a bit of a tricky statement with TL installs. Can you add `\listfiles` to the source and edit in the two file lists this produces.

Comment: The accepted answer to the second question you linked to might be helpful here. [Link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/diagnosing-the-too-many-math-alphabets-error/40767#40767)