# Using TikZ to draw Mayan numerals

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, mathabx

I am looking for a way to draw [Maya numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals) using TikZ.
What I want is a macro `\maya{21}` that gives me a graphical representation of the number 21 in the Mayan numeral system.

There is the package `mathabx` that provides something like this. But I can not use it, because I am using `mnsymbol` and there are some compatibility issues.

The following picture shows the symbols for each number in the maya system:

[image: Maya numeral system]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  How to do it?
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about [numbers above 19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals#Numbers_above_19)? What have you tried already yourself? Do you have an idea on how to get from `19` to three bars and four dots (mod and int functions)? The drawing with TikZ is really easy.

Comment: Have you considered doing [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118032/36821) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117971/using-mathabx-and-mnsymbol-in-the-same-document#comment262167_117971) instead of drawing?

Comment: –1: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Let me know when you edited your question and I’d be happy to redeem my downvote ;-)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I understand how to calculate it (see below), but the coding to get it as TikZ-picture seems not straightforward to me (mixing TeX if statements with TikZ code). What I (mathematically) would do is 21:20=1 remainder 1 and 1:20=0 remainder 1. This means I would draw a dot at the "20" position and one at the "1" position.

Comment: @Tobi Your effort is really appreciable. But in cases like this, the OP may say I don't know where to start. In such scenario, shall we try to add some code just as an illustration? I will do it for this question. Pour in your opinions. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Sure, it can be hard to find a starting point but in this case I'd expect that the OP at least had a look at the TikZ manual and drawing circles and lines isn't that complicated (the problems arise when you try to automate the numbering scheme) and he could explain how larger numbers should look like (He's explicitly asking  for that but he tells how to do it only after Qrrbrbilbel asked in a comment …)

Comment: @Tobi I agree. They can type at least the above code and in this case some dots and a bar additionally.

Answer (score 14):

You can copy the relevant code from `mathabx.sty` and `mathabx.dcl` to your document.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\newcount\mayacnta%
\newcount\mayacntc%
%
\def\mayaexpansion{%
    \mayacntc=\mayacnta\mathbfont
    \ifnum\mayacntc=0 0\else
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5\repeat
    \the\mayacntc\mayacntc=\mayacnta
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5 5\repeat}%
    \fi}%
\def\mayadigit#1{%
    \mayacnta=#1\hbox{\mathbfont\mayaexpansion}}%
```

The definition of `\mayaexpansion` has been changed accordingly to this [`answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142285/27635) of Werner to have properly rotated numbers (requires `graphicx`).

So, using the command `\mayadigit{<number>}` you can obtain what you want, as with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,MnSymbol}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\newcount\mayacnta%
\newcount\mayacntc%
%
\def\mayaexpansion{%
    \mayacntc=\mayacnta\mathbfont
    \ifnum\mayacntc=0 0\else
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5\repeat
    \the\mayacntc\mayacntc=\mayacnta
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5 5\repeat}%
    \fi}%
\def\mayadigit#1{%
    \mayacnta=#1\hbox{\mathbfont\mayaexpansion}}%

\begin{document}

$\mayadigit{0}\quad\mayadigit{9}\quad\mayadigit{19}$

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

---

### EDIT

I'm not really an expert in Maya numerals...

Try substituting the above code with this one to obtain numbers>20:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\newcount\mayacnter%
\newcount\mayacnta%
\newcount\mayacntb%
\newcount\mayacntc%
\newdimen\mayawidth%
%
\def\mayaexpansion{%
    \mayacntc=\mayacnta\mathbfont
    \ifnum\mayacntc=0 0\else
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5\repeat
    \the\mayacntc\mayacntc=\mayacnta
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5 5\repeat}%
    \fi}%
\def\mayarecurse{{%
    \mayacnta=\mayacnter \divide\mayacnter by 20
    \ifnum\mayacnter>0\mayarecurse\fi
    \mayacntb=\mayacnter
    \multiply\mayacntb by-20
    \advance\mayacnta by\mayacntb
    \hbox to\mayawidth{\hss\mayaexpansion\hss}}}%
%
\def\maya#1{%
    \mayacnter=#1
    \setbox0\hbox{\mathbfont 0}%
    \mayawidth=\wd0
    \left.
    \vcenter{\mayarecurse}
    \right.}%
\def\mayadigit#1{%
    \mayacnta=#1\hbox{\mathbfont\mayaexpansion}}%
```

and use the command `\maya{<number>}` instead of `\mayadigit{<number>}`, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,MnSymbol}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\newcount\mayacnter%
\newcount\mayacnta%
\newcount\mayacntb%
\newcount\mayacntc%
\newdimen\mayawidth%
%
\def\mayaexpansion{%
    \mayacntc=\mayacnta\mathbfont
    \ifnum\mayacntc=0 0\else
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5\repeat
    \the\mayacntc\mayacntc=\mayacnta
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5 5\repeat}%
    \fi}%
\def\mayarecurse{{%
    \mayacnta=\mayacnter \divide\mayacnter by 20
    \ifnum\mayacnter>0\mayarecurse\fi
    \mayacntb=\mayacnter
    \multiply\mayacntb by-20
    \advance\mayacnta by\mayacntb
    \hbox to\mayawidth{\hss\mayaexpansion\hss}}}%
%
\def\maya#1{%
    \mayacnter=#1
    \setbox0\hbox{\mathbfont 0}%
    \mayawidth=\wd0
    \left.
    \vcenter{\mayarecurse}
    \right.}%
\def\mayadigit#1{%
    \mayacnta=#1\hbox{\mathbfont\mayaexpansion}}%

\begin{document}

$\maya{0}\quad\maya{9}\quad\maya{19}\quad\maya{49}$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works fine for numbers below 20, thanks. It would be nice to have something working for larger numbers too.

Comment: @SimonSchläpfer Have a look at the edit to see whether it meets your needs.

Comment: Karl Congratulations on the 20k mark. :-) Now you are *trusted* sir ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I *think* this does it:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcount\mayannumber
\newcount\mayantmpa
\newcount\mayantmpb

\newcommand\mayan[2][]{%
\begin{scope}[#1,scale=1/4]%
    \mayannumber=#2\relax%
    \mayantmpb=20\relax
    \pgfmathloop
        \mayantmpa=\mayannumber
        \advance\mayantmpa by-\mayantmpb
        \ifnum\mayantmpa<0
        \else
        \multiply\mayantmpb by20
    \repeatpgfmathloop
    %
    \divide\mayantmpb by20\relax
    \tikzset{shift=(90:\pgfmathcounter*5-5)}
    \pgfmathloop
        \ifnum\mayantmpb=0
        \else
        \mayantmpa=\mayannumber\relax
        \divide\mayantmpa by\mayantmpb\relax
        {%
          \pgfmathloop%
          \ifnum5>\mayantmpa
            \ifnum0<\mayantmpa
              \foreach \i in {1,...,\mayantmpa}
                % Dot.
                  \fill (\i -\the\mayantmpa/2-1/2,1/4) circle [radius=1/4];
            \else%
              \ifnum\mayantmpa=\mayannumber
                % Shell
                \draw [thick, scale=5/4, shift=(90:2/3), line cap=round] 
                  (-60:1 and 2/3) 
                  \foreach \i in {-30,0,...,240}{ to [bend right, looseness=1.5] (\i:1 and 2/3)}
                  \foreach \i in {-60, -30,0,...,240}{ (0,-2/3) -- (\i:1 and 2/3)};
              \fi
           \fi
          \else%
            % Bar
            \fill (-2,0) rectangle (2,1/2);
            \tikzset{shift={(0,1)}}
            \advance\mayantmpa by-5
          \repeatpgfmathloop    
        }%
        \multiply\mayantmpa by\mayantmpb\relax
        \advance\mayannumber by-\mayantmpa
        \divide\mayantmpb by20
        \ifnum0<\mayantmpb
        \tikzset{shift={(0,-5)}}
        \path (-2,0) rectangle (2,1/2); % to enlarge bounding box
        \fi
    \repeatpgfmathloop
\end{scope}%
}
\begin{document}
%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \n [count=\i from 0, evaluate={\x=mod(\i, 5)/8*9; \y=int(\i/5)/8*12;}] in {0,...,19}{
 \mayan[shift={(\x,\y)}]{\n}
 \node [below] at (\x,\y) {\n};
}

\foreach \n [count=\i from 0, evaluate={\x=mod(\i, 5)/8*9; \y=-int(\i/5)/8*12-4;}] in {33, 56, 400, 429, 5425}{
 \mayan[shift={(\x,\y)}]{\n}
 \node [below] at (\x,\y) {\n};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun with PGF.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mayanumber[2][]{%
 \pgfpicture[#1]
  \pgftransformyscale{-1}
  \pgfmathdectobase\maya@{#2}{20}
  \expandafter\pgfutil@tfor\expandafter\maya@\expandafter:\expandafter=\maya@\do{
   \if0\maya@
     \maya@shell
     \pgftransformyshift{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya digitty yshift})}
   \else
     \pgfmathbasetobase{\maya@}{\maya@}{20}{5}
     \expandafter\maya@number\maya@\@@
   \fi
   \pgftransformyshift{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya digit yshift}}}
 \endpgfpicture}
\newcommand*\maya@shell{\pgfscope
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointscale{.5}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height}}}}
    {\pgfpoint{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width})}{+0pt}}{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height}}}
  \pgfusepath{clip,stroke}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@for\maya@@:=.2,.4,.6,.8\do{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\maya@@*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width})}{-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height})}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\maya@@*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width})}{2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height})}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }\endpgfscope}
\def\maya@number#1#2\@@{%
  \def\pgf@temp{#2}%
  \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty\expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\maya@number0#1\@@}
    {\begingroup\pgftransformxshift{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width})}
        \pgftransformxshift{-.5*(#2-1)*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya circle seps})}
        \pgfmathloop\ifnum\pgfmathcounter>#2\else
          \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height})}}{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height})}
          \pgfusepath{fill}
          \pgftransformxshift{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya circle seps}}
        \repeatpgfmathloop
       \endgroup
      \pgfmathloop\ifnum\pgfmathcounter>#1\else
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya digitty yshift}}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/maya bar height}}}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
      \repeatpgfmathloop}}
\pgfset{%
  maya digit yshift/.initial  =+.2em,
  maya digitty yshift/.initial=+.11em,
  maya bar height/.initial    =+.09em,
  maya bar width/.initial     =+.5em,
  maya circle seps/.initial   =+.03em}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  33 & \mayanumber{33}   \\
 429 & \mayanumber{429}  \\
2000 & \mayanumber{2000} \\
5125 & \mayanumber{5125}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]